# How to stop Xcode from thinking files are missing

Tags: xcode

I deleted some files from my project (a pair of .m/.h). 
However now every time I build Xcode warns that the files are missing (though the build is otherwise successful).

I can't see where/how Xcode thinks the files are needed, it must have some reference to them somewhere but I can't find it - the files are not listed in either the compile sources section nor the copy bundle resources section. Where else might they be listed such that Xcode feels the need to warn about them not being physically present?

Answer (score 3):

To delete them try this:

- create a file named like the missing one
- copy this file into your project folder, so that Xcode recognizes it
- right click on the file inside Xcode in the project view
- select delete
- select move to trash, when Xcode asks

This worked for me for files, however I have the same problem with empty folders. If somebody knows a way to get rid of the missing warning for them, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are missing from the project navigator or your checkout, but not included in the build for the current target, then the build might succeed despite the warnings.

XCode's Project Navigator keeps track of files, the directory they're in, and the state in git or svn. The project warnings when opening a project are shown in the status view at the top of the window. You can review these warnings when you press command-4.

The project navigator marks files that it tracks, but that it cannot find, in red in the folder view (press command-1 for that view). If you see red file names it might be that you deleted or moved them into another folder without XCode knowing about that. Then select the red filename and delete it.

On top of this the files might be "*missing from your work copy*", but still present in the repository. You can do two things in the terminal to sync with or delete the file from subversion.

1. svn up *file*
2. svn rm --force *file*